# batch echo string variable to text file returns Echo is off

Tags: batch-file

This is my current code:

```
cls
@echo OFF
echo 1>>test.txt
```

I know this is should be simpler but I cannot figure out how to print just the number 1 to the text file. I know putting quotes around the number 1 will make "1" print to test.txt, but I need it to just be the number one. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ah thanks worked perfectly!

Comment: `(echo 1)>>test.txt`

Comment: Please post as answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

`1>` is a special way of redirecting standard input and output.

If you had echoing on you would see cmd adding a 1 in front of your redirection, as you put a number there it doesn't bother.

The answer is to leave a space before the redirection character.

```
echo 1 >>test.txt
```

and leave `ECHO ON` and you'll see cmd change it to

```
echo 1 1>>test.txt
```

From The Windows NT Shell Scripting by Tim Hill

Table 2.4 Command Redirection Symbols

> **Symbol   Description**
>
> `>file`   Redirects command output to the file specified. You can also use a standard device name such as LPT1, CON, PRN or CONOUT$ as the file name. Any preexisting contents of the file are lost.
>
> `>>file`  Redirects command output to the file specified. If the file already exists, all command output is appended to the end of the file.
>
> `2>file`  Redirects command error output to the file specified. You can also use a standard device name such as LPT1, CON, PRN or CONOUT$ as the file name. Any preexisting contents of the file are lost.
>
> `2>&1`    Redirects command error output to the same location as command output. This makes any command output redirection also apply to command error output.
>
> `cmd1 | cmd2` Pipes the command output of cmd1 to the command input of cmd2. Multiple pipe characters are allowed, creating a chain of commands, each sending output to the next command in the chain.